# For all filenames in beautifulsoup file, return tags are empty

Tags: python, parsing, text, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm wanting to parse through a large .txt file and pull out bits and pieces of data based on their parent tags. The problem is, for example, the 'class = "ro" ' contains hundreds of different bits of text and numbers, most of which aren't useful.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/0000320193-18-000070.txt')

# load the data
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

# get the data
for tr in soup.find_all('tr', {'class':['rou','ro','re','reu']}):
    db = [td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td')]
    print(db)
```

As I said prior, this works to get all those tags, but 95% of the returns are useless. I want to filter based on the filename using a for loop or something that works similarly... "For all files with FILENAME = R2, R3, etc."... grab all tags with class 'ro', 'rou', etc. Everything I've tried thus far returns empties... can someone assist with this? Thanks in advance!

```
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>XML
<SEQUENCE>14
**<FILENAME>R2.htm** <------- for everything with this filename
<DESCRIPTION>IDEA: XBRL DOCUMENT
<TEXT>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
.....removed for brevity
</head>
<body>
.....removed for brevity
<td class="text">&#160;<span></span> <------ return this tag
</td>
.....removed for brevity
</tr>
```

Two samples files can be found here in their entirety:

(https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1800/0001104659-18-065076.txt) (https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1084869/0001437749-18-020205.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you want output but with bs4 4.7.1 you can use `:contains` pseudo class to filter filename tags

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/0000320193-18-000070.txt')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'lxml')

filenames = ['R2.htm', 'R3.htm']

for filename in filenames:
    print('-----------------------------')
    i = 1
    for item in soup.select('filename:contains("' + filename + '")'):
        print(filename, ' ', 'result' + str(i))
        for tr in item.find_all('tr', {'class':['rou','ro','re','reu']}):
            db = [td.text.strip() for td in tr.find_all('td')]
            print(db)
        i+=1
```